# trying to add userdetails from webservice on navigation drawer header

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer

I am new to android. I have being trying to implement job portal application. Now in trying to invoke webservices and getting responses. But my problem is that when I am calling webservice everything is working fine but user details like `username` and `email`, `id` are not displaying on navigation drawer header. Please help me out.
Here is my piece of code:

```
public class UserHome extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final CharSequence Vanaja = null;
    private static final int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
    public  static String OPERATION_NAME = "loginvalidate"; 
    static boolean errored = false;

    private static final CharSequence Home = null;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    protected ListView mDrawerList;
   private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    protected CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
  protected CharSequence mTitle;
    int childcount;

    // slide menu items
    protected String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;


   public  String emailvalue,passwordvalue;



String emailid="";

 String password="";

    SoapObject result;
protected ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    protected NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    TextView name,emailid1;

    public void getLoginValues(String emailid,String password)
    { emailvalue=emailid;
    passwordvalue=password;


    } 
    final String s=emailid;
    final String s1=password;
    /*public void getLoginValues(String editTextUsername,
            String editTextPassword) {
        emailvalue=editTextUsername;
        passwordvalue=editTextPassword;         
    }
    */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation1);



        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.industry11);
        emailid1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mail);




 try
 {
        final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD")));

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        AsyncTaskRunner async=(AsyncTaskRunner) new AsyncTaskRunner(this).execute();
 mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items11);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons22);

        mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slidermenu);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.userslider, mDrawerList, false);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    RelativeLayout update=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.update);
update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v){

         switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.update:

             //what to put here
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new ProfileUpdate());
             ft.commit();
         bar.setTitle("   Updae Profile");


         break;
      }




     }

     }
 );


       navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));



        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.icd2, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.drawer_open, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.drawer_close // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);





        bar.setIcon(R.color.transparent);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(1);
        }}
        catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */



    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
     Fragment fragment=null;
     String title="null";
        switch (position) {

        case 1:
            fragment =new SearchJobs1();
            title="";
           /* Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent1);*/
        break;
       case 2:
           fragment =new LatestJobs();
        /*  Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Homepage.class);
            startActivity(intent2);*/
            break;

        case 3:
            fragment =new AppliedJobs();
        /*  Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FindPeopleFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent3);*/
            break;

        case 4:
            fragment =new ChangePassword();
          /*Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CommunityFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent4);*/
            break;

       case 5:
           fragment =new Unsubscribe();
         /* Intent intent5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PagesFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent5);*/
            break;


        case 6:
            fragment =new LogOut();
         Intent intent6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;

        /*case 6:
            fragment =new ContactUs();
          Intent intent6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PhotosFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment =new AboutUs();
          Intent intent6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PhotosFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;*/


        default:

            break;
        }

       if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position-1);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position-1]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

        getActionBar().setTitle("  " + mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    public void setActionBarTitle(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getActionBar().setTitle("  "  + string);
    }

     public void setActionBarImage(ImageView view)
        {
            Log.d("Tittlename", "image   is"+view);
            getActionBar().setCustomView(view);
        }





     private  class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>        {

            String result1;
            UserHome outer;
            public AsyncTaskRunner(UserHome outer) {
               this.outer = outer;
            }
            private String TAG;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
                WebserviceCall service=new WebserviceCall();
try
{
/*if(isNetworkAvailable())
{*/


    SoapObject result;
result=service.invokeLoginWS(emailvalue, passwordvalue, OPERATION_NAME);



/*
    String s=outer.emailid;
    String s1=outer.password;
=======

    /*String s=UserHome.this.emailid;
    String s1=UserHome.this.password;*/

/*  
result=service.invokeLoginWS(s,s1," ");*/


    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vi.inflate(R.layout.user_home, null);
           String resultvalue=result.getProperty("firstname").toString();
           emailid= result.getProperty(0).toString();
           password = result.getProperty(1).toString();
name.setText(resultvalue);
 resultvalue=result.getProperty("emailid").toString();
 emailid1.setText(resultvalue);
/*else
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(),InternetProblem.class);

      startActivity(intent1);   
}*/

}
catch(Exception e)
{  
Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

refresh.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run()
   {
    try {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InternetProblem.class);

          startActivity(intent1);
                } 
    catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
});  

}
/*Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                refresh.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try {
                            serviceCall();
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });  */

/*                  int childCount = result.getPropertyCount();
*/                 
                return null;
            }




            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");

                               }


        }
}
```

Comment: That's a **lot** of code for a question. You should try to isolate the problem to a smaller code snippet.

Comment: String resultvalue=result.getProperty("firstname").toString();
emailid= result.getProperty(0).toString();
password = result.getProperty(1).toString();
name.setText(resultvalue);
resultvalue=result.getProperty("emailid").toString();
emailid1.setText(resultvalue); Did you put break points in this code and see what is the value that you are setting ?